# Spring JDBC PreparedStatementCreator Invalid Api Usage

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, prepared-statement

I´d like to know how to use the [PreparedStatementCreatorFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/).  As far as i [read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23994196/2749837) it goes like the following code, except that in rare examples not only the sql is given to the factory but also an int[] types, but i dont´t want to pass in hundreds of types, as jdbc usually retrieves the types based on the java types if you pass params as object[]. I´m using Spring 3.1.3 RELEASE.

```java
   public int addEntityAndGetId(String name, String address){
        String sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (NAME,ADDRESS) VALUES (?,?)";
        Object[] params = new Object[]{name,address};
        PreparedStatementCreatorFactory factory = new PreparedStatementCreatorFactory(sql);
        PreparedStatementCreator psc = factory.newPreparedStatementCreator(params);
        KeyHolder generatedKeyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

        jdbcTemplate.update(psc, generatedKeyHolder);
        return generatedKeyHolder.getKey().intValue();
   }
```

But all I get is an org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException.

Do i really need the types? As on every jdbc update statement you can just pass an object[] and its fine.

The purpose of this question is to get around the need to specify any column type and to avoid PreparedStatementSetters on crud queries by letting jdbc determine which column type is appropriate for which object.

Comment: Have you actually read that stack trace? It is a `ClassNotFoundException` so you are missing a jar file on your classpath. You are missing spring-tx.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for pointing out. I´ll fix this. Though this does not solve the problem. The question is why does this statement not work? And how can i get it to work, if possible without specifying the column types?

Comment: The statement should contain the same number of placeholders as arguments. A single ? won't work if you have multiple arguments.

Comment: @M.Deinum i edited the question, of course i use a correct array and this is not the problem also. the error lies in my opinion in the usage of the factory and the creator.

Comment: What error do you get. The classnotfound isn't related to anything in the query it prevents basically everything... So what is the error you get when executing the query....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 different errors. One symptom and one cause.

First the symptom : you get a `ClassNotFoundException:
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException` because you are missing `spring-tx` in classpath as M.Deinum said. Add it because you will get troubles if you don't.

Next the cause. You create your factory with `new PreparedStatementCreatorFactory(sql);`. The javadoc says : *Create a new factory. Will need to add parameters via the addParameter(org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter) method or have no parameters*

You declare the type of parameters neither in the constructor of the `PreparedStatementCreatorFactory`, nor in the call to `newPreparedStatementCreator()`. So Spring issues the exception.

And no, you cannot simply pass an `Object[]` to an update statement, because the underlying JBDC call will need the actual type of the objects (there are `setInt`, `setString`, ... methods).

Now for the fix. As you will pass 2 strings to the update method, you should create the factory this way :

```
PreparedStatementCreatorFactory factory = new PreparedStatementCreatorFactory(sql,
    new int[]{Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR});
```

(assuming the type of the columns is `VARCHAR`)

But that's not enough. As you want to get back the generated primary key for the new inserted row, you must declare it :

```
factory.setReturnGeneratedKeys(true);
```

And lastly, if you use PosgreSQL, you could have to use

```
generatedKeyHolder.getKeys().get("id");
```

instead of simply `generatedKeyHolder.getKey().intValue()` (assuming the name of the column containing the generated key is `id`)

Comment: OK got it, as of now it is possible to pass an object[] to the jdbctemplate and jdbc does the mapping itself without any specifying the column types. do you know if this is also possible by using the creatorfactory?

Comment: AFAIK, according to the javadoc (and to your current problem ...) my answer is no : you have to pass the parameter types in the constructor of the factory.